How to Duplicate Loop Cut while keeping distance?
How can I duplicate my Loop cut and move them slighlty down to make shelves ? I have tried to use Shift + D while creating my loop cuts but it didn't create any new faces and it didn't work.


You probably shouldn't duplicate. Just use Ctrl+R to add loop cuts

Not sure what you mean, maybe select the edges you want and Ctrl B to bevel?

If you select the horizontal edges and bevel them with ctrl+B you could give them thickness, if that's what you mean.

For something like this you are probably better off selecting the faces, insetting them individually by pressing 'i' twice, and then extruding them back

